# Finding distribution of r.v. by using the Laplace transform

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, laplace-transform

In the book *An Intermediate Course in Probability* by *Allan Gut* there is this exercise

> For a positive, (absolutely) continous random variable $X$ we define the Laplace transform as,.
>   $$L_{X}(s)=E\,e^{-sX}=\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-sx}f_{X}(x)\,dx, \quad s>0.$$
>   Suppose that $X$ is positive and stable with index $\alpha \in (0,1)$, which means that
>   $$L_{X}(s)=e^{-s^{\alpha}},\quad s>0.$$
>   Further, let $Y\in \text{Exp}(1)$ be independent of $X$. Show that
>   $$(\frac{Y}{X})^{\alpha}\in \text{Exp}(1)\qquad (\text{which means that}\quad (\frac{Y}{X})^{\alpha})\stackrel d= Y.$$

I am thinking that I should solve this by using

> $$ X^{-\alpha}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda X}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda,\quad x>0,\quad \text{and}\\
> Y^{\alpha}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{\alpha -1}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{Y}}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda,\quad y>0.\\
> (\frac{Y}{X})^{\alpha}=(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda X}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda)\times(\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{\alpha -1}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{Y}}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda),\quad X,Y\text{ independent.}\\
> f_{(\frac{Y}{X})^{\alpha}}(x,y)= (\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{\alpha-1}e^{-\lambda f_{X}(x)}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda)\times (\frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\lambda^{\alpha -1}e^{-\frac{\lambda}{e^{-y}}}\, \mathrm{d}\lambda)$$

But here I am stuck. I do not know how to go from here. How to evaluate this Intergal? Anyone who can leave a hint? I would be very thankful.

Comment: @Math1000 That is not true though, dividing the mgf of $Y$ by the mgf of $X$ doesn't tell us anything about $Y/X$ (consider $X$ and $Y$ having the same distribution).

Comment: @SofiaFredriksson Note that $f_{(Y/X)^\alpha}$ is a univariate pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write out the cdf for $(Y/X)^\alpha$, then find the pdf by applying the Leibniz rule and use the formula for the Laplace transform of $t f(t)$:
$$F_{(Y/X)^\alpha}(x) =
\operatorname P(Y < x^{1/\alpha} X) =
\int_0^\infty d\tau_1 f_X(\tau_1)
 \int_0^{x^{1/\alpha} \hspace{2px} \tau_1} d\tau_2 f_Y(\tau_2), \\
f_{(Y/X)^\alpha}(x) =
\frac d {dx} F_{(Y/X)^\alpha}(x) =
\int_0^\infty d\tau_1 f_X(\tau_1)
 \frac d {dx} (x^{1/\alpha} \tau_1) f_Y(x^{1/\alpha} \tau_1) = \\
\frac {x^{1/\alpha - 1}} \alpha \int_0^\infty
 \tau_1 f_X(\tau_1) e^{-x^{1/\alpha} \hspace{2px} \tau_1} d\tau_1 =
-\frac {x^{1/\alpha - 1}} \alpha \frac d {ds} \int_0^\infty
 f_X(\tau_1) e^{-s \tau_1} d\tau_1 \bigg\rvert_{s = x^{1/\alpha}} = \\
-\frac {x^{1/\alpha - 1}} \alpha
 \frac d {ds} e^{-s^\alpha} \bigg\rvert_{s = x^{1/\alpha}} =
e^{-x}.$$